# How to automate text writing in popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate text writing in popup. Is it possible? if yes, then please guide me. Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: you should try to be *a lot* clearer in you question. Explain the context. What kind of popup ? Native (like alert, confirm) ? Not native (like divs which pops up over the document a la jquery-ui) ? Is there an input in it ?. If it's a DOM Element that contains an input, then yes, it's possible, and easy...

Comment: Hi Grooveek, thanks for the reply. In my case, popup is comming when I am clicking on some button on the website. In this popup, I need to fillup the entries and save them. Is it possible to automate this?

Comment: If it is a popup window you need to switch the control to it before entering the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("id of the view to enter text in the popup")).sendKeys("some text to enter");
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a browser popup, it sounds like you're looking for:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("some text to enter");
```